# Finding the best fit for the data

Tags: curves, nonlinear-system, least-squares, data-analysis

Hi guys i am trying to use the normal equations to fit some data to find values a and b for the following equation.

$$y=a*b^x$$

The data was given to me below and this is what i am currently using

[image]

My attempt at the question can be seen below

$$log y = log(a*b^x)$$
$$log y = log a +logb^x$$
$$log y = log a + x log b$$

$$Y = log y, A = log a, B=log b$$

$$Y = A + Bx$$

[image]

Based on the data given i got the following normal equations since it is linear form

$$7a_0 +3.9a_1  = 66.7$$
$$3.9a_0 -  2.95a_1 = 48.85 $$

Solving the simultaneous equations gives the following values for
$$a_0 = 1.12, a_1=15.09 $$

Therefore we re substitute to get back the actual values
$$log a = 1.12$$
$$a = e^{1.12}$$
$$log b = B = 15.09$$
$$b = e^{15.09} = 3576874.742$$

Therefore the equation is of the form

$$y = 3.605*3576874.742^x$$

Therefore i know something is wrong with the equation but i am not sure what it is can anyone help to get the values for a and b and show me what i am doing incorrectly?

Comment: To @Amir: the second column in your table is incorrect, there you will have $\log y_i$. Because this remark, you will have to modify last column as well...

Comment: so take  log of each the y values and adjust the column for y and the last column respectively @AntonVrdoljak

Comment: Yep, try like that!

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak do we have to log the x values as well ?

Comment: See your last equation, i.e. $Y=A+Bx$, then $x$ in that equation is the same $x$ as in your initial equation $y=a \cdot b^x$, and $Y$ is nothing else than $\log y$...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak when i use log of the y values and solve the equation for a and b i try a simple test by substituting my x values to see if i will get back my y values but i am still not getting that to happen. $$y=1.568*2.25^{0}$$ i get the value of 1.568

Comment: I used GeoGrbra and got this: $y=2.845 \cdot 6.415^x$.

Comment: im not sure how u came up with that solution can you share the solution @AntonVrdoljak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106421/discussion-between-amir-and-anton-vrdoljak).